# Is there a way to recover private key from a certificate signing request?

Tags: 14.04, openssl

Trying to install an SSL certificate.. Managed to produce a self signed certificate. But have lost the Private Key (Certificate Signing Request) for the certificate that I purchased. Do I have to get the certifcate re-issued or are they saved somewhere? Can only see ssl-cert-snakeoil.key in /etc/ssl/private/

Comment: What instructions did you follow in order to generate the CSR?  The location of the private key will depend on how you did it.

Comment: I used this snipped of code.. `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr`

Comment: I found the key.. It was located in `/root/` directory.. I am guessing it is because I never stated a directory on the command. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The principal of cryptography means that you cannot find out the private key from the public key or from the CSR.  Both the public key and the CSR may be shared with other people without them being able to know your private key.

If you have lost your own private key, you will need to generate a new one, get a new CSR based on it, and apply for a re-issue of the certificate.  You cannot continue to use your existing certificate if you no longer have your private key.

If you simply don't know where your private key is, then it will be located somewhere on the computer on which you generated the CSR.  Most instructions for generating a CSR involve generating a private key and a CSR that is based on the private key, saving the private key on your filesystem somewhere.

Comment: Okay cheers.. I used this code to generate the CSR.. Where would have the private key been? `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr`

Comment: I found the key.. It was located in `/root/` directory.. I am guessing it is because I never stated a directory on the command. Thank you for your help.